# Identity Bathroom Sink Faucet Cartridge

Tags: bathroom, faucet, sink, cartridge

Trying to identify what type of cartridge this is to replace it due to a leak. This is the cold water side. No shut-off valve so have to turn the water completely off to take it out. Has a metal plate and two very small holes in the bottom. Bought a similar size but different style on the bottom and it did not work.
Image link since I can't attach:

[image]